# configurepython argparse help file

Tags: python, argparse

I have a argmarse as:

```
 parser.add_argument('--lim',
                      nargs=4,
                      type=float,
                      help="Plot limit as x.min, x.max, y.min, y.max")
```

which, at help, comes up like:

```
--lim LIM LIM LIM LIM
                        Plot limit as x.min, x.max, y.min, y.max
```

Is it possible to reformat it as:

```
 --lim 4*float      Plot limit as x.min, x.max, y.min, y.max
```

or at least as

```
 --lim 4*LIM      Plot limit as x.min, x.max, y.min, y.max
```

Comment: try the `metavar` parameter

Comment: @hpaulj: metavar controls what will be written so, `LIM LIM LIM LIM` can be replaced as "FLOAT FLOAT FLOAT FLOAT", but can not be grouped as 4*FLOAT,

Comment: Ok, you have to subclass the HelpFormatter, and change the method that generates that part of the help string. That shouldn't be hard if you can read Python code.   There have been SO asking about alternatives in formatting the help line, but I don't recall one just like yours.